# Struts2, change project's web browser URL?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

Struts2, eclipse.

Is there another way of changing the project's web browser url, except of renaming the project?

Example:

My dynamic web page project name: ***MyProject***

Url: http://localhost:8080/MyProject

now I want to change that url to: http://localhost:8080/Project, but keep project name ***MyProject***

tnx.

Comment: This probably depends on how you have configured Eclipse to deploy your application. What server are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Comment: This question isn't Struts2 specific. You will want to figure out how to change the context path for your web application. javamonkey's link may be your best first step.

Comment: @javamonkey: yes, thats the way to go from. i tought it was strtus2 specific. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the url pattern in the web.xml which will do the trick.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/project</url-pattern>
        <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is application server / servlet container specific. You should lookup relevant infromation about **context path**, this is what defines your application's URL after host and port name.

In your example, `http://localhost:8080/MyProject`, context path is `MyProject` and you must change that in your app. server / container configuration.