# Tomcat error 404 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat

I had this Spring project running fine, but today I started getting creepy error 404 on the web debugger each time I debug on Tomcat my project.

As part of resolving this issue, I have deleted the old tomcat7 and added new one, changed its location to the default one on:/Server/TomCatv7.0 at localhost. went to the Overview menu and selected use Tomcat instalation.

when I type in: localhost:8080/ I got Tomcat homepage.

How can solve debugging my dynamic web project?

Comment: You can start by showing us your `web.xml` or `ServletContainerInitializer`.

Comment: Go to your tomcat manager and see if your application is deployed : localhost:8080/manager/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default eclipse will deploy the webapp to a context derived from your project name, so for tomcat to serve the Tomcat homepage at the root context `/` would be correct behavior because your webapp is likely deployed in `/myWebApp`.

You can tell Eclipse to deploy to a different context by following the steps in my answer at [Changing Tomcat context path of web project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522054/changing-tomcat-context-path-of-web-project-in-eclipse/9522230#9522230)