# Specify context-path for spring-boot WAR

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web application that deploys as a WAR. Right now when I deploy it to my Tomcat 7 server, it uses the name of the war file as the context, such as /myartifactid-1.5.4.SNAPSHOT/. I want to specify the context-path, but

```
server.contextPath=/mywebapp
```

seems to only work for embedded tomcat. I've added a META-INF/context.xml with only this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="false" path="/mywebapp" />
```

but that hasn't had any effect.

EDIT: This is NOT a spring-boot issue, but instead related to how NetBeans behaves differently from Eclipse. NetBeans apparently recognizes the context path parameter in context.xml, but Eclipse doesn't. In Eclipse you have to modify the Web Projects Settings to set the context path.
[Changing Tomcat context path of web project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522054/changing-tomcat-context-path-of-web-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: It's not necessarily related to differences in the behaviour of Eclipse and Netbeans: I'm having the same problem when deploying without an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are packaging your Spring Boot application as a war (as opposed to a jar with an embedded tomcat container) the context path will be the name of the war.

For example if you name your packaged application `mywebapp.war` and you place it under Tomcat's webapps, it will be available under `/mywebapp`

Comment: I understand, I just thought that setting the context path in context.xml would override this.

Comment: @GalenYoder I see your point. However I haven't done that before so I can't give you any more details on it

Comment: am also im trying to set it

Answer (score 0):

when the war  does not have the same name with the project, the application will not be accessible via the context path on the tomcat,
to fix this you need to go to the POM.xml change the  name of package to match the context path name

```
server.servlet.context-path=/virtualcard 

    <groupId>com.test.csc.virtualcard</groupId>
        <artifactId>virtualcard</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>virtualcard</name>
```

then the war will be: virtualcard.war