# Servlet context isn't set only when building a WAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

We are moving from Spring `WebInitializer` to Spring boot 2.5.0 `SpringBootServletInitializer`

We need to add a context path for our Servlet dispatcher, with the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { JmsAutoConfiguration.class, ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,
            SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
    public class WebServerConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Bean
   public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
       return factory -> {
           factory.setRegisterDefaultServlet(true);
           factory.setContextPath("/servlet");
       };
   }
}
```

When running Maven WAR regular Tomcat 8.5, the Servlet context isn't set, log:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Regular Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebServerConfig.class, args);
}
```

When running embedded Tomcat code works as expected:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/servlet]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Maven pom:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.boot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.boot-version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also have `configure` method:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
  SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(WebServerConfig.class);
}
```

Am I missing code/property to enable Servlet context when building a WAR?

I found older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665548/specify-context-path-for-spring-boot-war) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856043/changing-the-context-path-of-deployed-spring-boot-war-on-a-container-tomcat-se) without a real answer except using different war name.

Comment: You need to override/implement the `configure` method of the `SpringBootServletInitializer` else it won't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added also `configure` method to my question

Comment: From those snippets it is impossible to tell, and your config also looks weird. Also depending on your Spring Boot version Tomcat 8.5 might be too low and you require tomcat 9.

Comment: And ofcourse the `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` doesn't apply when deploying as a war file. That is for controlling the creation of the embedded tomcat, spring Boot cannot control an external tomcat. So the context path (which is something different than a servletcontext (which threw me off) will not be set).

Comment: @M.Deinum with tomcat 9 same results, so what is the equivalent to Spring `ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("Mydispatcher", ds); dispatcher.addMapping("/servlet/*");`

Comment: Ofcourse you will get the same results, as I mentioned that thing doesn't apply. Remove that line and add `spring.mvc.servlet.path=/servlet/*` to your `application.properties` (at least that is what your code snippet of the servlet registration implies which again is different than the context path, so which is it you want to set?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed the issue by adding property inside `SpringApplicationBuilder`:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    Properties bootProperties = new Properties();
    bootProperties.setProperty("spring.mvc.servlet.path", "/servlet");
    return builder.sources(WebServerConfig.class).properties(bootProperties);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below application property to set the context path for spring boot application.
If  you are using yaml configuration.

```
server:
   servlet:
     context-path: /servlet
```

If you are using application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path = /servlet
```

Comment: It affects only embedded tomcat and not when deploy war

Comment: your war file name will be the first context path example application.war then your context path would be host:port/applicaiton/contextpathInProperty/controllermappinngPath. Give the war name as root conext path

Comment: I use root so My filename is ROOT.war

Comment: you want to change the root context in war or after the root path?

Comment: It sounds that same, I'm building spring boot application and deploy to war and I need /servlet as context path although my war is ROOT.war

Comment: change your war name to servert.war then it will work. I mentioned above the war name will be your context path.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not a full solution, we have another application as MY.war that we need the context path to be servlet/MY