# Setting up home page in spring

Tags: spring

I am new to spring environment. I have created small test spring project through STS.
Project name: SPTest
base package name: uk.co.ifTest

When I run and open this project browser through Eclipse. It work fine, but url, it put in the browser is xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/ifTest/, instead of //xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/SPTest/.
I guess, it is adding base package name.

Is there any way I can open project with http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/SPTest/.

Thanks
ish

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your context path for the server to point from ifTest to SPTest.

This answer will help you identify how to do it:
[Changing Tomcat context path of web project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522054/changing-tomcat-context-path-of-web-project-in-eclipse)