# How to set Tomcat configuration/context.xml in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, config, jndi

I'm developing java web application using `Tomcat 8` and `JNDI Datasource`. I have defined resources via context.xml in `META-INF/context.xml`. This settings run fine on Tomcat 8.

But I need to have context.xml file outside of project/war, [there are several options](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-context). So I have chosen this option:

> Individual XML files located in
>   $CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/

So if I deploy app named `projectA` to Tomcat 8 and create file `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/projectA.xml` with content from file context.xml, app runs again fine! But there is a problem with development in Eclipse and settings.

In Eclipse I have created server: `Server->Tomcat 8` and I have set path to the same directory Tomcat 8 as above. Now I can see in Eclipse `Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config`, which contains context.xml, server.xml and so on, but no directory ../Catalina/localhost from Tomcat 8 conf directory. So I have created this directories and copied projectA.xml there:

[image: Tomcat setting]

Unfortunately it doesn't work, Tomcat 8 by Eclipse doesn't know about this directories with .xml files (file not found exception...). Is there any possibility how to set path to context.xml (projectA.xml) on Tomcat 8 in Eclipse for specific application?

Comment: Can you share your server.xml

Comment: This discussion may answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522054/changing-tomcat-context-path-of-web-project-in-eclipse#9522230