# removing project name from j2ee web application URL

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, web

I have a web dynamic project in eclipse and index.html in webapps folder, I am able to access it by :

```
http://localhost:8080/javaTest
```

I want to access my application by :

```
http://localhost:8080
```

I tried changing context-root to "/" by right click on project->properties->Web Project Settings, but on `http://localhost:8080/` getting the requested resource not found, and application is still running on `http://localhost:8080/javaTest`.

This is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>javaTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Edit : server - tomcat 7.0.34

Comment: Which J2EE server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods from the wiki of tomcat

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem referring the below link.

[How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Be **Sure to follow the all the steps**

Comment: please briefly describes content of the link in case it gets broken

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove apllication name or project name from your URL , jsut change in tomcat server file conf/server.xml file.

appBase="webapps"

remove "webapps" and just use "/"

appBase="/"

Now you check http://localhost:8080