# 404 error when going to my service folder ion apache server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache, cxf

When routing to my webservice folder (localhost:8080/myproject) all i see is 404 error. 
Note : I have changed the server location , so now the main page of the apache server loads up ok. 
What may cause this problame?

Comment: I assume you are expecting to see a listing of available services generated by CXF?  Can you post your web.xml or web-fragment.xml?  Specifically, what servlet-mapping are you using for your CXFServlet?

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to you have configured different context root for your application than that of myproject. e.g. context root allows you to have different url than that of the actual folder name. Below link might help you to do that.

[How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: No, that is not the  issue. I tryed what you said , it wont work. To be even more specific, even when i choose "run on server" , the default page is loading on eclipse browser, and still 404.

Comment: Note, I am using cxf , if it matters.

Comment: Installing CXF plugins for eclipse seems to solve the problem.