# Set Context Path in Dynamic WebProject

Tags: java, eclipse, contextpath

I'm trying to set the context path for a web project,  but I was not able to save it directly in eclipse.

Then I thought of directly making the change in the file to avoid this.

[image]

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Which file holds the context path in the webproject -  look at my base structure before answering the question.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to .setting folder under project folder.

.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component

search for property "**property name="context-root"**" then set the desired value.

[image]