# Unable to generate pdf using domain server URL

Tags: jsf, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

i have pdf generator

```
<h:outputLink value="printpdf?id=#{assetDetailData.id}" includeViewParams="true" target="_blank" >PDF öffnen</h:outputLink>
```

EXAMPLE

i am using `wkhtmltopdf`

**localhost:8080/suess/printpdf/?id=3457** (works fine)

on server

**148.251.123.83:8080/suess/printpdf/?id=3457** (works fine)

works fine

BUT WITH DOMAIN

**www.mydomain.at/printpdf/?id=280** (IT DOES NOT WORK)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What erros you ll getting exactly?

Comment: not getting any errors, but it does not complete action.

Comment: what about `www.mydomain.at:8080/suess/printpdf/?id=280` ?

Answer (score 0):

> By default, the context root of the web application (also called the context path) is set to the root name (the name without the .war extension) of the Web Application Archive (WAR).

So you have to change the root context. In your case the root context is "www.mydomain.at/suess", but you need "www.mydomain.at". You can change your root context in your application server configurations.
[Instructions for JBoss](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowDoIOverrideTheWebContextRoot)
[Here a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: @haisi So you mean I have to remove <display-name>suess</display-name> from web.xml file ??

Comment: @star95 I don't think so, because the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1043408) specifies it as "The optional display-name element specifies the Web application display name, a short name that can be displayed by GUI tools.".  
What application server are you using? Just search for the specific   instruction on how to change the context root path of said application server.