# java project deployment with different name

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I want to deploy existing project with different name 
that is my project running on

```
http://localhost:8080/App/application.htm
```

now I would like to change URL

> `http://localhost:8080/myproject/application.htm`

For this I changed name in .project file and change the folder name,
but when I try to deploy on tomcat, It takes old name

please guide me that where should I make changes

Comment: are you creating .war file for deployment.

Comment: no sir..I just deploy project in tomcat through myeclipse

Comment: project is built in spring and hibernate

Comment: Its better to create .war file of your project with your expected name and deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you clean and republish your project to "activate" the new URI. This is done by right-clicking your server (in the Servers view) and choosing Clean. Then you start (or restart it).   [Refer this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: I am not getting clean option by right clicking on server. in the server vew

Comment: refer the link provided, I thin it will help you