# 404 error with Jersey REST service on Tomcat9

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, http-status-code-404

So I am trying to create a REST service using Jersey 2.25 which is to run on Tomcat 9. I am using gradle as build tool. Basically, I am following [this vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) and I did everything as mentioned there. But, when I try to run it on tomcat9 by visiting http://localhost:8080/com.krozona.jersey.first/rest/hello, I get a 404 error.

Here's my web.xml :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.krozona.jersey.first</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.krozona.jersey.first</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My resource class:-

```
package com.krozona.jersey.first;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

And finally, my build.gradle :-

```
 /*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [http://localhost:8080/rest/hello](http://localhost:8080/rest/hello)?

Comment: Yes, no luck there as well, still getting 404

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 404 error with Jersey Tomcat service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422448/getting-404-error-with-jersey-tomcat-service)

Answer (score 0):

As in the [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) mentioned:

> This URL is derived from the context root value in the projects
>   properties Web Project Settings (by default, this is your application
>   name),  augmented with the servlet-mapping URL-pattern and the hello
>   @Path annotation from your class file.

So be sure to use the right URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/{your application's name}/rest/hello
```

The port number must also be correct.