# how to change request URl in Jsp or Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

index.jsp

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%="This is First App" %> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

web.xml file :

```
 <display-name>JSPAPP</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

when i run the app http://localhost:8080/JSPAPP/index.jsp using its work fine But i have change this URL to http://localhost:8080/MyFirstApp/index.jsp i.e i have to change JSPAPP to MyFirstApp how i will change please tell me .

Comment: how are you deploying the app or are you running from eclipse?

Comment: yes i am running from eclipse how i wll change it from eclipse

Comment: move index.jsp file to webapps/MyFirstApp folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Comment: what about in servlet how i will change it

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyFirstApp/index.jsp its not working when i move index.jsp to MyFirstApp folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  if you are using eclipse to run the application then  change the context root from the project "Properties --> Web Project Settings --> Context Root".

2)  if you are deploying your app to a server (say tomcat)rename your war file to the context root you desire.

Comment: I have tried to follow first one but i am unable to run it

Comment: I have change Contextroot to MyFirstApp but still  .http://localhost:8080/JSPAPP/index.jsp its running like this while http://localhost:8080/MyFirstApp /index.jsp i want his

Comment: you don't need any changes in servlet.After changing the context root in project properties you have to remove your web application from Tomcat (using Add and Remove... on the context menu of the server), redeploy, then re-add your application and redeploy  refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse