# Can't get a Java Spring webapp to deploy to Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, web-applications

I've got a project in Eclipse, with a `.war` file inside it. I'm using Spring for the project, with the help of Maven too.

I've installed Tomcat 8, but I'm having trouble deploying the webapp to Tomcat. The Tomcat runs without errors and the console output of launching the Tomcat looks like it is successfully deploying it, however when I go to localhost is just displays the generic Tomcat home page saying I have successfully deployed Tomcat.

I've tried changing my server location to use the tomcat installation, I've changed the location in the properties of my server to not be the workspace metadata.

When I add jars to the tomcat, I click on my project, and under it it lists the Spring jar if that is of any relevance.

I don't really know what else to put here at the moment, but I'm at hand to respond immediately to any questions or any more info that you require.

Thanks.

EDIT:
http://localhost:8080, it leads me to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy54R.png
My tomcat console output is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/J-Owens/8164b3ec6dbed9986322/raw/6756486aad0092647bbea8f315c42ac5ba9550b1/tomcatconsole

Comment: What is the URL that you are using to view your page?

Comment: http://localhost:8080, it leads me to this: http://i.imgur.com/82lmpai.png
My tomcat console output is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/J-Owens/8164b3ec6dbed9986322/raw/6756486aad0092647bbea8f315c42ac5ba9550b1/tomcatconsole

Comment: You're probably hitting the `http://localhost:8080` which corresponds to the context root of the `root` web application (this usually comes bundled with the Tomcat). Try accessing your app, by `http://localhost:8080/contextRootOfYourApp`. You can control the context root of your webapp on eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334309/934307.

Comment: You can even check the context root of your app using the `Manager app` button on the home page you've shown in your image. You should setup appropriate permissions beforehand, of course, though. Read about it here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html and here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each war file will have a name associated with it. When you use `localhost:8080` as the URL, Tomcat will use the `war` with name `ROOT` under `tomcat/webapps` to display on the browser. By default, Tomcat will have a `ROOT` war that comes with the tomcat bundle. If you need to open your project, you will need to use `localhost:8080/<your-war-name>` to open your project's page. Alternatively, you could remove everything under `tomcat/webapps` and rename your `war` to `ROOT` to be able to access your project pages with the `localhost:8080`.

Comment: From the gist that you have posted, looks like your project is packaged as `Alpha-1.war`. Try the URL `localhost:8080/Alpha-1` and see if that works

Comment: You got it working! Is there any way to get it running under localhost:8080 without renaming it ROOT? What if I have sub web pages, will that be affected by renaming the folder in tomcat/bin to ROOT?

Comment: Renaming it to ROOT will be for the entire project. So even the subpages can be accessed this way.  I'm not sure of any other method other than renaming to ROOT.