# Automatically set application context in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: web-applications, intellij-idea, ide

I've been developing web applications in Eclipse and recently decided to give a shot to IntelliJ Idea. My webserver has about 15 artifacts and in Eclipse they were automatically assigned application context based on their names. Now in Idea it defaults them all to "/" which is obviously incorrect. Can I somehow set it to automatically define application context based on artifact name or do I have to enter them all manually? Sorry if that's a newbie question, I tried googling it and searching inside various settings for Idea but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the web server you're using. For Tomcat, you have to either manually set the context path of the deployed artifacts (in Deployment tab of Tomcat Server) or configure your web server's specific settings, like server.xml for Tomcat ([see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/java-how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse))

For other servers, like JBoss for example, each artifact is deployed with web context named as the artifact itself.

Comment: Thanks! Was using Tomcat :)