# Automatic 'Application context' for Tomcat server in Intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a Tomcat server in IntelliJ. I'm trying to `automatically generate the application context based on the artifact name`.

I have an `artifact called Foo`. I want the Tomcat deployment Application context to be `/Foo`. In Eclipse this will automatically happen (potentially from spring config setup by someone else). However, I can't find a way to do this automatically in IntelliJ. It seems I have to go in by hand and type in each artifact path manually.

It's essentially the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32777131/automatically-set-application-context-in-intellij-idea), which indicates the Tomcat server needs to be setup differently, but I don't understand how the accepted answer actually actually solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [doesn't support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120242) it at the moment. You need to specify artifact deployment context manually.