# Struts 2 Hello World

Tags: eclipse, struts2

I have a problem at this [example](https://struts.apache.org/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html)

I work with eclipse for Java EE and Apache Tomcat 8.
My project structure:

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/xtevpxgef/stackstruts2.png]

The web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Hello World Struts 2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The other files code is the same as the struts website.
 When I run the index.jsp file I get the following error:

> **HTTP Status 404 - /helloworld/index.jsp
>
> type Status report
>   message /helloworld/index.jsp
>   description The requested resource is not available.**

Can someone spot the reason why can't I run it?

Comment: I run it locally:http://localhost:8080/helloworld/index.jsp

Comment: What is the context at which the app was deployed?

Comment: If you mean the "web project settings" option for this project , the context root is helloworld

Comment: It's the name of the project, not the app context.

Comment: Do you mean the java version used at project facets and the runtime at project facets?

Comment: it's called context root in eclipse

Comment: Wrong class path in `filter-class`. Don't access jsp-s directly, use actions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the project is created by using Maven configuration, and to access the Struts action you should use url

> #### Step 6 - Build the WAR File and Run The Application
>
> Execute `mvn clean` package to create the war file.
>
> Copy the war file to your Servlet container. After your Servlet
>   container successfully deploys the war file go to this URL
>   `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/index.action` where you should see
>   the following:
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [apache.org](https://struts.apache.org/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.data/Struts2HelloWorld.png))</sub>

Web application context is where the application was deployed. In the docs url it's `/helloworld`, on the image it's `/Hello_World_Struts2_Ant`. Use it as a part of the url. It doesn't matter which app context did you use during deployment but url depends on it. If you want to change the web app context you should read [Java - How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse). After the context you use action name with `.action` extension to execute action.

Don't use URLs like `localhost:8080/helloworld/index.jsp` because you might not get the resource because it's already handled by the web server.

Comment: I changed the context root to "app" and I used the action name with the .action at the URL but I got the same message again. Am I still doing something wrong? Or it needs maven structure to work? I used exactly the same project  structure shown as at the image, not the maven structure.

Comment: You should not get the same message again, if you did what is said in the tutorial. Of course you need a maven to work with, without it it doesn't work.