# Java Spring localhost project name into URL

Tags: java, spring, url

Imported an example project to my workspace which URL, lets say, looked like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/Example/login
```

Then I copied example project, renamed/refactored until it worked. 
My question is, where I can change the URL string that follows localhost ?
At the moment, the URL is still same, but I want mine to be like:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyProject/login
```

I must mention, that on "Run on server" when it is loaded, the automatic URL is:
http://localhost:8080/Example/ ... the login part must be added manually and after that controller recognizes it.

It seems like, the name after localhost is taken from ProjectName, but I renamed it after copy. Is there in some document where the change is needed to make manually ?

Comment: if it is a maven project you need to change you project name in pom.xml and after that remove the app from your application server than redeploy it.

Comment: It should be in the your `@Controller` function or `@RestController` where `@RequestMapping` is currently "Example". If this is not the case then it's probably due to the login and hence a spring security thing in which case you'll need to look at the security configuration java file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask myself, answer myself.
The answer is found here: [How to change context root of a dynamic web project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse)

Firstly: Change Web project settings under **Properties - Web Project setting - Context root** if it is not already done

Secondly: After that under Server list: Right click on server and clean.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which server you are using 
assuming tomcat goto server.xml file and change as follows
put the context tag inside host tag

```
    <Context docBase="MyProject" path="/login">
```

refer to the reference of context tag for more https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/context.html

Assuming you changed your project name to MyProject