# Override eclipse project name?

Tags: java, playframework, sbteclipse

It appears the sbteclipse plugin generates the name in .project from the playframework project name (also the folder name).

Is there a way to override this?  I have two apps that I'm developing, both named 'web' (but in different nested project/trunk/etc folders).  Going by the default, I end up with two projects named 'web' in eclipse, which doesn't work.

If there's no way to override the eclipse project name, any suggestions on better project structure/management that avoids this issue?

Comment: You can change the name in web.xml

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I realized that the playframework project name is the first line in the build.sbt file (name := """web""").  Changing that line resulted in the sbteclipse outputting a different project name.

Thanks for the comments.