# Spring MVC app not running, throwing 404 when accessing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have started some spring mvc application and deployed to WAR to web server. Deployed with out any issue but when using the URL on browser, i'm getting 404 error.

Web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

[App Struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mChq.jpg)
    Controller class

```
public class WeatherController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/CityWeather", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String weather( Model model) {
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.weather" />
```

Comment: add `<annotation-driven />` to servlet-context.xml

Comment: And you have added @Controller annotation over WeatherController class right?

Comment: Both the changes you have mentioned were already there.

Comment: move servlet-context.xml to the same folder where web.xml is

Comment: and adjust path in <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>

Comment: Ok. Let me make those changes and see. App started responding with views now even with out those changes when using http://localhost:8080/weather/CityWeather. Where did this weather came from when my controller says /CityWeather?

Comment: That's contextpath.. you must have gave it somewhere

Comment: Is there a common place where it might be given? I don't recall where I've given it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215689/4828463