# Can't display the table when running index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

In my web app the welcome page needs to show a table. However it (http://localhost:8080/MyApp ) shows "null" , but if I add 'ServlentToRead.java' I mean, http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ServlentToRead it displays the table.

Why I can't  get the table as first page ? here is the index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
    String table=(String) request.getAttribute("table");

%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Mytable</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Mytable</h1>

<%= table %>

</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are you using as a server? Tomcat?

Comment: The reason why you are seeing the table on the other url is because it is mapped to a Servlet. You need to map your welcome file to that servlet if you want to see it not as null also. Please post your web.xml

Comment: Yes, I do use Tomcat

Comment: You need to change context root of the application. By default it is the servlet name. What to change depends if you are running it stand alone of from eclipse. Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Comment: If you are deploying it stand alone set the war name to ROOT.war

Comment: edit your answer and add your web.xml found in WEB-INF folder

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I added my web.xml page

Comment: no that doesn't help, please post the "source" for your web.xml. Not the "design". You can change to source by clicking on the tab called "source" inside your web.xml towards the bottom of the page

Comment: check out my answer and try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why I can't get the table as first page ?

change your web.xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
<display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>ServlentToRead</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

You will now see the table whenever you visit the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp
```

**EDIT:** sorry, remove the forward slash from in your web.xml:

```
<welcome-file>/ServlentToRead</welcome-file>
```

so it looks like this:

```
<welcome-file>ServlentToRead</welcome-file>
```

Comment: HTTP Status 404- Not  Found: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists...Why?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!!!!!! Does it mean I don't need the file index.jsp?

Comment: good to hear. No you still need the index.jsp file. The Servlet with the url mapping "ServlentToRead" forwards the request to that index.jsp file. Feel free to upvote or mark as the correct answer if it helped.