# Why does a web application got an error when clicking on hyperlink?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, web-applications

The app welcome page is running however when I'm clicking on hyperlink it shows an error:

> Type Status: Report
>
> Message: /Welcome/nextPage
>
> Description: The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing

My guess it is something to do with the web.xml file. One of my attemps was to write the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WelcomeServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NextPageServlent</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/NextPageServlent/nextPage.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NextPageServlent</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NextPageServlent/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

However it doesn't help, I have the same problem

**edit:** 
hyperlink that leads to 'nextPage'

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>


<%
    String table=(String) request.getAttribute("table");

%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>table content</title>

</head>

<body>

<h1>table content</h1>

<p>
<a href="nextPage">go to the next page </a>
</p>

<%= table %>


</body>
</html>
```

the web page link: http://localhost:8080/Welcome/nextPage

Is there a way not to use web.xml file?

Comment: Clicking on WHAT hyperlink?

Comment: clicking on nextPage...which suppose to show the nextPage

Comment: How is the main page generated? What does the hyperlink look like?  There is too much information and detail missing here.

Comment: The main page generated with: index.jsp, WelcomeServlet.java, ReadQuery.java .....hyperlink  (in the nextPage.jsp): <a href="updateForChangeStock">See the stocks' states changes</a>

Comment: Add the `index.jsp` to your question.  Also, open a browser, navigate to the main page, right click on the link and copy the URL to your question so we can see what is actually happening.

Comment: Paste the entire page code here to show what's going on. There seem to be something missing

Comment: Also check google for the error message, it points out several reasons which may apply to your case

Comment: @NitinSingh the page code of newPage.jsp?

Comment: @NitinSingh I didn't found something helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created index.jsp in webcontent

```
Welcome <a href="next">next page</a>
```

In xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NextPageServlent</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/NewFile.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NextPageServlent</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/next/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

NewFile.jsp is also inside the webcontent

Works perfectly

Comment: In index.jsp you have wrote... what does the  'Welcome' stands for?

Comment: its just a text nothing to do with the code you can write anything you want. Ignore the 'Welcome'

Comment: i found the source of the problem. You have used the "NextPageServlent/*" in url pattern Why ?

Comment: Thanks A LOT!!!!!! but why I get null instead of a table? (jsp file of a Welcome page and the one of the next page use similar code... actually that is why my welcome-file in xml is WelcomeServlet and not index.jsp (since index.jsp gave null instead of a table but WelcomeServlet shows the table, the WelcomeServle is java code )....How to make the next page run properly, what changes should be done in web.xml?  )

Comment: this is the link of your another problem. Right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477922/cant-display-the-table-when-running-index-jsp

Comment: Ok so in the index.jsp you are requesting the attribute "table" and the in the servlet you are inserting the value in the table attribute. so if you directly open the index.jsp you will get null because the value is not inserted yet. To insert the value you will need the middle man and the "WelcomeServlet" is the middle man. don't hesitate to ask again if have still some doubts..

Comment: and by the way use "/next" in the url pattern to know the use of '*' check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Is "nextPage.jsp" is inside the folder "NextPageServlent" if not then just put

```
<jsp-file>/nextPage.jsp</jsp-file>
```

instead of

```
<jsp-file>/NextPageServlent/nextPage.jsp</jsp-file>
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: I did as you said ( "nextPage.jsp" wasn't inside the folder "NextPageServlent") but still the same error...Is the servlet-mapping part correct?

Comment: what is the path of nextPage.jsp ?

Comment: /MyApp/WebContent/nextPage.jsp

Comment: you haven't removed the '/' from "/nextPage.jsp" right ?

Comment: the '/' is  still there

Comment: check the spellings ... try to copy and pest as mush as possible