# Spring - Hibernate HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im using Spring + Hibernate to create CRUD app. 
I have problem with showing my page even when i type : 
"http://localhost:8080/tdt/customer/list" 
It shows : HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
I have tried to clean project, i have tried to refresh project, and i have tried to restart the server. 
Im (using Windows 7) if that matters.

Here is my folder structure and message: 
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSims.png)

Here is my code : 
package main.controller;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import main.dao.CustomerDAO;
import main.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // need to inject the customer dao
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model theModel) {

        // get customers from the dao
        List<Customer> theCustomers = customerDAO.getCustomers();

        // add the customers to the model
        theModel.addAttribute("customers", theCustomers);

        return "list-customers";
    }

}
```

DAO : 
package main.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import main.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    // need to inject the session factory
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        // create a query
        Query<Customer> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

        // execute query and get result list
        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

        // return the results       
        return customers;
    }

}
```

Here is spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlets.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="main" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer_baza?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="admin_crm" />
        <property name="password" value="admin_crm" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>



</beans>
```

And web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: When you deploy, did you set up application context to /tdt/? Did you try access by this url http://localhost:8080/customer/list"?

Comment: @Maxim Kasyanov still same, 404

Comment: As @Maxim said `@RequestMapping("/customer") ` is the context in your controller.
You are accessing `tdt/customer/list`
Try accessing `/customer`
Or try changing `@RequestMapping` to `/tdt/customer`

Comment: how you deploy application?

Comment: i have changed @requestmapping and i still have the same result, 404

Comment: are you trying to run the application in `Eclipse`?

Comment: @Maxim Kasyanov I run it on server

Comment: @Shreyas yes, im trying

Comment: There is problem with your `ContextRoot` i guess.
Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse

Comment: are you testing your application in embedded tomcat (or any other container) or as a standalone (tomcat) application server with war? If the latter is the case, you need to check whether the war name is indeed tdt.

Comment: @Merve Sahin i am running it on eclipse, right click - Run on server

Comment: where do you put your html files? Is the view resolver able to find the views in `/WEB-INF/view`?

Comment: @Merve Sahin .jsp files are in /WEB-INF/view folder